# Auto power off for 220 V AC cable breaks

Tags: power

Can anyone suggest a circuit to automatically cut power when 2 core 220 V AC cable tied on poles powering 12 V SMPS at different locations breaks between any poles? There is lot of monkey menace.

**__________________________________**

EXAMPLE ONLY of use case:

There is lot of monkey menace

[image]

Sumatra, 2009.
:-)
Genuine photo(s)  but badly edited.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF1pMM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using a "remote-control over mains" transmitter and receiver to prove line integrity.*

There are a range of devices using the X10 protocol for home automation. I can't recommend any particular product (and we don't do that on this site anyway) but there should be something suitable for the scheme shown in Figure 1.

- On power up the RESET button is pressed. This energises RLY1 and provides power to the 220 V line.
- An X10 transmitter at the far end of the line is wired for constant 'ON' 
  transmit.
- An X10 receiver at the feed end monitors this signal and once received it latches RLY1 on. The RESET button may now be released.
- If the transmitter signal is lost the receiver should drop out and remove power from the relay coil. The line power will be disconnected.

X10 devices may be expensive - I don't know - but there are sure to be many similar systems available in various price ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be connectivity to the end of the cable.

I assume that current monitoring is not sufficient, as the wanted load can vary, so lacks discrimination with respect to a break at the penultimate pole.

An 'out of the box' solution would put a 'LAN over mains wiring' LAN adapter at the far end of the cable. A suitable host, say a tablet or a Beaglebone, continuously pings it. If the pings time out, it cuts the supply at this end.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly (?), you want to essentially "turn off" the power when it is interrupted.  I have used used a simple relay exactly like the one shown at the left end of the circuit shown by @transistor.  You must press the "Reset" button to turn on the power to the load (the SMPS), but if the power is interrupted, the relay drops out and prevents powering the load until it is "Reset" again.

This is necessary in cases where you don't want the load to re-start by itself (without supervision) for whatever reason.  Or in cases where the power is intermittent or unreliable and when the power is interrupted, it is prudent to wait until the problem is located and repaired before attempting to re-power the load.

You don't describe exactly what is the motivation for needing this function, so we can't directly address your specific issue.

Comment: He wants to kill the supply if the monkeys break the wires anywhere along the pole route.

Comment: There is lot of monkey menace :-)

Comment: If you want to do this from the source end, then one method is to get some sort of "feedback" from the destination end to alert that the power has been interrupted. As suggested by transistor and Neil_UK.  Another method would be to monitor the current that is going into the line. If the normal load is CONSTANT, then you can simply monitor the current (with a simple current transformer) and cut the power when there is any change (higher current from a short fault, or lower current from an open.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and obvious answer is to use a residual current breaker. Any current not flowing through both wires simultaneously is a strong indication of cable tampering or failure. RCDs use a ferrite core that both AC wires pass to measure a difference current and when this difference current excedds about 30 mA the device trips: -

[image]

Here's the problem and solution more pictorially: -

[image]

And here's an RCD: -

[image]

In the US and Canada they are called GFCI (ground fault circuit interrupter) and please note that this works without measuring or needing an earth wire. Will 30mA kill a monkey is a different question that I can't answer but 5 amps will!!